# python regular expression extracting between quotes

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

```
title = str(Soup.find('td', {'id': 'bxgy_x_img'}))
title_re = re.compile('alt="(.*)"')
title_pat = re.findall(title_re, title)
```

For some reason this doesn't just grab Title, how do I make it grab Title?

The HTML this is being run on is as follows:

```
<td id="bxgy_x_img">
  <alt="Title" id="bxgy_img_a" height="75" border="0" />
</td>
```

Comment: Are you using BeautifulSoup? If so attributes are available as if they were keys to a dict, e.g. td['alt']

Comment: The [`alt`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt_attribute) element looks unusual for HTML. If it would be preceded an `img`, this would get you an answer: `soup.find('td', {'id' : 'bxgy_x_img'}).findChild('img')['alt']`, which would simply print *Title*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
title_re = re.compile('alt="(?P<title>[A-z]*)"')
```

Comment: `[A-z]` matches more than just `[A-Za-z]`, so I'm not sure if that's what you really meant to do.

Comment: alt = "Title", where Title can be anything. I am just trying to extract what is between the quotes with alt=

Comment: Use `[^"]*` do match anything *except* quotation marks. Makes much more sense here.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the `*` is greedy, meaning it will match all the way to the '"' after `border="0"`. Try restricting the pattern to just letters and numbers using `[A-Za-z0-9]+`.

Comment: inside the " " it may have both letters and numbers

Comment: Or make `*` non-greedy: use `*?` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're really looking for is something more like:

```
title_re = re.compile('alt="([^"]*)"')
```

Where `[^"]` means "anything but a double quote character." It doesn't strictly conform to HTML valid characters, I don't think (newlines specifically), but it should work for your purposes. Also, you'll need to parse HTML entities -- e.g. `&quot;` -- if you want to capture the actual intended value.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML appears to be broken. When BeautifulSoup parses `content`, it only interprets `<alt="Title" id="bxgy_img_a" height="75" border="0" />` as an empty `<alt></alt>` tag:

```
import BeautifulSoup

content = '''\
<td id="bxgy_x_img">

<alt="Title" id="bxgy_img_a" height="75" border="0" />

</td>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(content)
title = str(soup.find('td', {'id': 'bxgy_x_img'}))
print(title)

# <td id="bxgy_x_img">
# <alt>
# </alt></td>
```